# csv to pandas.df to numpy to prepare data for tensorflow

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

Hi might need some help..

Just starting of with Python and programming, so sorry if this is real beginner question.

I have the following:
Starting with a csv file like that..

```
1,2,3,4,5
2,5,6,8,9
4,7,6,8,7
#EOL
2,3,4,5,7
5,6,8,9,1
4,7,8,8,7
#EOL
2,3,4,5,7
5,6,8,9,1
4,7,8,8,7
#EOL
```

I need those values to go into a 3D array to play a bit with TensorFlow.
I struggle with the following.
Consider this an "image" where the
the values in a row in the csv is a dataset for one location in my "image". Lets call it "RGBXY".
So first row is upper left pixel in the "image". Next csv row is next "pixel" in the "image" and so on...till #EOL. From here it is the newt row in the "image". The example above would be a (3x3x5) array

Goal is to build this in a 3D array.
I tried to just grab a df = pd.read_csv("") but this will give me strange types (object) for my arrays which I somehow can't cast to get used at the end.I guess because of the #EOL string.
Also defining the shape is a bit complicated.
Is there an easy way to build this?

Answer (score 0):

You should treat the .csv as a regular .json, to sort out which lines are #EOL from the rest. Then, just retrieve the data in a long string, split it, convert it to float and use a numpy array with .reshape in the shape you want your data.

This will do the trick:

```
import numpy as np

data = [] # Where we'll keep the data
eol_lines = [] # Where we'll store the number of lines in an #EOL block

# Open the .csv file
with open(csv_path) as file:
    accumulator = 0
    for line in file.readlines():
        # Remove the eventual spaces and line returns
        line = line.replace(' ', '').replace('\n', '')
        # Only keep non #EOL lines
        if line != '#EOL':
            data.append(line)
            accumulator += 1
        # Keep track of the #EOL block's number of line
        else:
            eol_lines.append(accumulator)
            accumulator = 0

# Turn the data in a long string
data = ','.join(data)
# Turn the data in a long array
data = data.split(',')
# Turn strings in floats
data = [float(x) for x in data]
# Reshape the data
data = np.array(data).reshape((3, 3, 5))
```

This also counts the number of lines per #EOL block because, to be honest, I don't fully understand how you'll define your image's size.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work!

The size of the image would be like this....?
data = np.array(data).reshape((eol_lines[0],len(eol_lines), 5))

Just need to count the the elements in a row !?

Comment: Seems to be what you need! Next time you post a question, try to make sure all dimensions of the problem (such as the number of EOL blocks and the number of line per block) is different, so that there is no confusion between the quantities.